# t-sql how to use the condition Like [Please Enter StudId or Enter for all] & "*"

Tags: t-sql

I have made some researches but I can't find any help for this one. I want to convert this Access condition to t-sql but I don't know how. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Please see here. It's pretty simple. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/ms179859.aspx

Comment: Sorry for late response, but the link is good! Thanks, Hockenberry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to replicate that behaviour in MS SQL Server Management Studio because the Access GUI is oriented to all type of users while Management Studio is oriented to developers.
The solution to your dilema is:

1. Create a Stored Procedure with an input parameter @StudID (according
   to your query this appears to be a VARCHAR or NVARCHAR)
2. In the SProc's body you need to put the SQL statement you want to use,
   but with a tweak: ***SELECT .... FROM ... WHERE (StudID LIKE @StudID + '%'
   OR @StudID IS NULL)***. Hence, pass @StudID as null if you want to retrieve all records (equivalent to "or Enter for all").
3. Either create an application on top of the SProc, or give your users access
   to the new SProc and nothing else they don't need.

Comment: Thanks William C. It works! :)